# Azure Mobile App refreshing tokens on server

Tags: authentication, xamarin.forms, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

Here's the background:

- Need to authenticate with google/facebook/msa
- Need to add our own claims to `MobileServiceAuthenticationToken` for use on client
- Want to have refresh token capabilities (I know FB doesn't have that)

I have this working by `LoginAsync` and getting a  `MobileServiceAuthenticationToken` back.  Then I call a custom auth controller which has an `[Authorize]` attribute on it.

The custom auth controller copies some claims from the principal then adds our claims to those and creates a new token which it returns to the client.

Using the `LoginAsync` for all of this keeps the tokens flowing for all calls and that's great.

So, the token expires and I call `RefreshUserAsync` on the client.  At this point the `MobileServiceAuthenticationToken` with our custom claims is replaced by the default one from the MobileAppService without our claims.  I expect that.

So now I have to call the custom auth controller again to get our claims added back to the identity token.

This works, but it feels clumsy.  And it's two round trips.

What I'm looking for is to refresh the identity provider access token on the server side, and in the same method, update the identity token with our stuff.

I'm aware of the `/.auth/refresh` call from the client side as an alternative to `RefreshUserAsync`.  Is there a similar call I can make from my controller in the backend without setting up the whole `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` thing?

For example: I use `this.User.GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<GoogleCredentials>( this.Request )` in the backend to get identity provider information without making HTTP calls.

Something like that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version - no.

Longer version - you need to call the /.auth/refresh on the backend on behalf of the user, then add your claims.  The /.auth endpoints are on a different service that your backend does not have access to except via Http.

The `GetAppServiceIdentityAsync()` method still does a HttpClient call, so you aren't saving yourself a round trip.

Comment: Since I don't know what's going behind the scenes this could be a silly assumption... but do I need to do anything with the response that comes back from the backend generated call to `/.auth/refresh`?  Is something updated internally that I can't see?  Because I've just copied all the headers from this.Request to my backend HttpClient and made the call and it seems to be working.  Seems too easy :).

Comment: Actually, I am getting new access tokens each time and they're ending up in the credentials.  Perfect.  Thanks, Adrian!

Comment: The /.auth/refresh endpoint returns a new access token.  You then decode the access-token, add your own claims to it, re-sign it and return it to the user in the same format.